# my manual flush() does not have effect on my second persist()

Tags: jpa, entitymanager, flush

I wanted to test flush to understand it, and wrote a code :
- with FLUSMODE not in AUTO but in COMMIT mode
- with express flush() to synchronize database

But, the result isn't what i expected.
can you see the code. 
Exception is only thrown when commiting and not at second persist() call !

```
EntityManager eMgr = emFactory.createEntityManager();
eMgr.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

EntityTransaction tx = eMgr.getTransaction();
tx.begin();

    persistPersonne(eMgr);
    eMgr.flush();
    eMgr.clear();
    howManyPersonsInDatabase(eMgr, "after 1st persistence");
    // here, method gives to me : 1 person (correct)
    // (if i do not flush before --> 0 person)

    persistPersonne(eMgr);
    // here, should throw an exception, as my second persist is forbidden 
    // (due to integrity contraint)
    // but NO! --> exception is thrown when commiting..

tx.commit();
// exception is thrown here!!!!!
```

Comment: You set the flush mode to commit. So the flush happens... at commit time. Why would you get an exception when calling persist()? persist() doesn't commit, so it doesn't flush, so it doesn't write anything to the database, so the database can't possibly tell you that you violate a constraint.

Comment: i don't agree. 1- Because if there is already a person in database (before excuting code), the code don't stop at commit but at the first call of persist() method. So, it doesn't wait for commit action to throw an exception. 2- i explicit call the flush not to wait commit action. if the flush method() would have to wait to commit action, it would be useless to put it inside the code.

Comment: What you're saying is in complete contradiction with the comments in the code you posted. The comments say that the first persist and flush succeed as expected, but that you expect the second persist to fail, and that instead the commit is failing. Your question explitly says *Exception is only thrown when commiting and not at second persist() call!*. Which is normal since, as I repeat, persist() doesn't flush, and thuse doesn't send anything to the database, which thus can't throw any exception.

Comment: in my first snippet code, i start with nothing in database. After 1st persist, flush seems to be correst as it says to me "1 record in database" but 2nd persist just after doesn't fail : and this is my real problem : why do i have to wait commit action to fail ? in my last comment, i explain that the code can immediatly fail just after the 1st persist (and not commit) when my record is ALREADY in database. So, we don't need to wait commit to fail. My real problem is to understand why in my snippet, as flush seems to work, my second persist doesn't immediatly fail.

Comment: Again: because persist() doesn't flush. So nothing is written to the database when you call persist(). So the database can't possibly tell you that there is a constraint violation. Data is written at flush time, and the flush happens when you commit. Enable SQL logging, execute your code step by step, and look at the queries that are executed (or that are NOT executed) at each step.

Comment: ok. i'll do that and say to you. But i absolutly do not understand why, if my record is already in the database, it immediatly fails after persist() call, before the flush and before the commit. in fact, you say persist do not write, ok, i know that, but java has the information there is a contraint of non duplication. now, in my snipet code, AFTER my first persist, java seems to know there is a record as i flushed, so has the knowledge, but do not fail at second persist. Moreover, when i change FLUSH-MODE to AUTO, it exactly fails at second persist, so BEFORE the commit. this is not logical.

Comment: No, Java doesn't. Constraints are set in the database, and verified by the database. Remember that many transactions, in many instances of your Java application, or of any other application, can use the same database concurrently. The database is the only place where integrity constraints are checked.

Comment: ok, java doesn't know. So, in a FLUSH MODE which is AUTO, 1st persist is accepted and 2nd is refused (exception thrown) , but commit has not occured yet. regarding to what you say, java shouldn't know 2nd persist should be forbidden.

Comment: ok, you 'are right. Flush make the synchronization and is triggered when asked. In my example i thought i triggered persist on calling method but not, i triggered persist just after, by calling the flush. thanks.